# PHP parameter without value using for navigation

Tags: php, parameters, navigation, get

I am trying to set up a navigation system that uses GET parameters with no value, here's an example:

http://foo.bar/?mainPage
takes the visitor to the main page.

So I am using if statements and I am wondering if there is a way I can do this without a bunch of if statements? I don't think switch statements would work for this. This is currently what I have:

```
$mainPage = $_GET['mainPage'];
$contact = $_GET['contact'];

if(isset($mainPage)) {
    // go to main page
}

if(isset($contact)) {
   // go to contact page
}
```

I don't want to have to end up writing a ton of if statements, though. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: and what about `http://foo.bar/?mainPage&contact` ? you should look at MVC Routing, its a pretty simple concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, which gives everything in the URL after the question mark, then just use a switch statement to choose which page.

Comment: @somewalri Mind me asking why you accepted this answer over mine?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using an associative array:

```
$location_map = array(
    'mainPage' => 'some-url-here',
    'contact'  => 'some-other-url-here'
);

foreach($location_map as $key => $value)
{
   if(array_key_exists($key, $_GET))
   {
      header('Location: ' . $value);
      exit();
   }
}
//if we reached here, then redirect to home page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a header redirect like so:

```
<?php    
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
?>
```